# Substring of a link String

Tags: java, string

I would like to get only the actual link of the following link string:

```
String link = <a href="http://www.facebook.com/wwwausedu" target="_blank" class="btnFacebook">Link to Facebook</a>
```

The result should be only `www.facebook.com/wwwausedu`

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
TEMP = link.substring(link.indexOf("http://")+1, tmp.lastIndexOf("\""));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the last index of `"`, but the first one **after** your `http://`:

```
TEMP = link.substring(link.indexOf("http://")+7, link.indexOf("\"", link.indexOf("http://")));
```

The [`String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) function gets the first occurence of `str` after the specified index. Also, as pointed out by @mellamokb the Wise, you need to add `7` to the index, not `1`, since you want to exclude `http://` from the result.

Comment: +1 Also you need `link.indexOf("http://")+7`, not `+1` (http://ideone.com/QPNnlR)

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise .. you are right but why is it +7 .. i thought we take the index right after the backslash of http://

Comment: @HayaRaed: `indexOf` matches at the beginning.  So when it finds `http://`, it returns the index at the *start* of the expression it found, just before the `h`.  Since you want `TEMP` to start with the `www`, you need to offset by the length of `http://`, which is 7 characters long.

Comment: If I will apply the same concept on:  <a href="/info/200147/current_students/397/leadership_program">Leadership</a> ............................................ link.substring(link.indexOf("<a href=")+8,link.indexOf("\"", tmp.indexOf("<a href=")));

Comment: @HayaRaed You're right, the principle is the same. However, I guess you want a `9`, because there's also a `"` after `=`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use tool specially designed for parsing HTML like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

```
String link = "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/wwwausedu\" "
        + "target=\"_blank\" class=\"btnFacebook\">Link to Facebook</a>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(link);
String address = new URL(doc.select("a").attr("href")).toString();
```

This will return: `http://www.facebook.com/wwwausedu` but we just want part without protocol so lets use URL now

```
URL url=new URL(address);
System.out.println(url.getHost()+url.getPath());
```

Output:

```
www.facebook.com/wwwausedu
```

Comment: +1 Despite being overkill in isolation, it's the best approach if one wants to do many different manipulations in some HTML text (and also to support more protocols besides `http` in the `href`)

Answer (score 2):

Try using Regex

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(link);
    String url = null;
    if (m.find()) {
        url = m.group(1); // this will give you the URL
    }
```

**Edit**:
To remove the *http* too use the Regex "href=\"http://(.*?)\""

Comment: Almost. OP wants to find http://**www.facebook.com/wwwausedu** part so instead `href=\"` try `http://` :)